# External Monitor + MBP 2016 15" TouchBar no 60Hz option on any resolution w/ DP; works on 2018

Tags: macbook-pro, display

I have two MacBooks Pro 15" w/ TouchBar, one 2016 and one 2018.

On the 2018, I was able to get 4K@60Hz (and 1080p@60Hz, along with most all other resolutions at 60Hz) using a USB-C to DP dock to a DP -> HDMI active converter.

However, on the 2016, using same peripheral/connectors/configuration, I'm unable to get any output at 60Hz. All resolution options presented are limited to 30Hz max (800x600, 1600x900, 1920x1080, 3840x2160, etc. at 30Hz only).

I've tried in both extend and mirror modes, closed lid and open lid. I'm using option-click to see resolution/refresh rate options. I've attempted to clear my NVRAM and PRAM as well, but can't tell if I've cleared them successfully.

Does anyone have any suggestions? At this point, I'm even happy with getting 1080p@60Hz on the 2016. All documentation and online resources I've found have stated that 60Hz should be supported at 1080p w/o any issues on the 2016, and 4K using the DisplayPort.

Comment: Please edit or add into a comment the version(s) of macOS running on these 2 Macs; the manufacture and model of the DP Dock; the make and model of the monitor(s) you're connecting; and lastly, the make & model of HDMI active converter. Have you tried directly connecting the '16 to the display device(s), bypassing the Dock?

Comment: Graphics card need to support it too.